# Simple query on firebase with angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I am new to firebase and trying to retrieve data from it. I have *denormalize* my data. Each comment has an userId and every users have all the comments id with them.

I was able to retrieve individual comments or users but I don't know how to list a user with all his comments.

This is my code to retrieve user 1 (jack):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable} from 'angularfire2';


@Component({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/user-page/user-page.html',
})
export class FousiorPage {
    user: any;
    comments: any;


    constructor(
        private navCtrl: NavController,
        private af: AngularFire

    ) {

        af.database.object('/users/1').subscribe(result => {

            this.user = result;
            console.log("this.user: ", this.user);

            //this.comments = ???
            //How to get all the comments from firebase for user/1 Jack?
            console.log("this.comments: ", this.comments);  

        });
    }
}
```

This is the json tree that I have imported into firebase.

```
{
    "comments": [
        {
            "content": "How are you?",
            "author": {
                "0": true
            }
        },
        {
            "content": "I am good. Last night dinner was fantastic",
            "author": {
                "1": true
            }
        },
        {
            "content": "What did you have?",
            "author": {
                "2": true
            }
        },
        {
            "content": "It was a French dish made by Joanna's mum.",
            "author": {
                "1": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "John",
            "comments": {
                "0": true
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Jack",
            "comments": {
                "1": true,
                "3": true
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Kat",
            "comments": {
                "2": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the result I get in Firebase:

[image: Firebase data]

Answer (score 0):

You can filter on the list.

```
users.filter(function(user){
return user.id == user.comment.id
})
```

Comment: I would like to query firebase again to get all the comments from user/1.

Comment: @Dee, would you share your solution here? I look for the same and it seems that you found it. Thanks!